# Not able to start debugging in visual studio after setting up custom error pages

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis, visual-studio-2012

I have a WCF Restful service hosted on my local IIS. I have some custom error pages defined for some error codes e.g.401,403,500 and so on. I have set up IIS for these error pages.

Navigate to IIS > Virtual Directory > Error Pages(From Feature View) >Edit Feature Settings in Right Actions pane.

[image]

When I set this setting, my custom error pages works fine but I'm not able to start debugging in visual studio when I run my project as:

[image]

but when I go to IIS > Virtual Directory > Error Pages(From Feature View) >Edit Feature Settings in Right Actions pane and set Error responses as mentioned below:

[image]

It starts debugging but now error pages are not custom but default IIS error pages.